# static library linkage issue using eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, pthreads, linkage

I have two projects, one that creates static library and the other one that is using it.
The first one, create a file called liboutputdevice.a.
When I build it, everything goes OK.

Then I have my second project that uses the library above, 
and including `#include "outputdevice.h"`
and calles to a function:

```
initdevice("sdfs");
```

Which is declared on outputdevice.h and ipmlemented in the static library above.
The tester project linked to the first project by going to: Cross g++ Linker, libraries and library search path.

When I'm building that project (The tester, second one), the first one is getting an error, with `Undefined reference to 'pthread create'`
Suddenly...
(although I included the -lpthread in the compile process of the first project).
Someone can tell what it the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your compiler/IDE where the include files are. Notice, that library files (usually with a .lib extension) and include files (.h or .hpp) are not the same. While libraries have to be added to the linker (as you did correctly), the include files must be accessible from the project base directory as well. 
If the main path of the includes is not the same as of the project, you have to tell the compiler, were it should look for additional includes. 
Usually this is done by the -I option of the compiler call, e.g.

```
g++ main.cpp -I path/to/other/includes/dir
```

You can also set it up directly in the project preferences of your IDE.